# How to get ms.graph.app.graphUserScopes from azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How to get `ms.graph.app.graphUserScopes` and `ms.graph.user.license.skuId` from Azure?

I opened the application on Azure but I didn't find it out.

Where can I find it to integrate it with the Java Spring project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the `ms.graph.user.license.skuId`
run below query in Graph explorer:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/licenseDetails?$select=skuId
```

[image]

To find the `ms.graph.app.graphUserScopes`  make use of below query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/oauth2PermissionGrants`
```

[image]